# Why is launchd (launchctl) on Mac OS X 10.6.8 on a Mac Pro preserving launch time values across reboots?

Tags: mac, reboot, launchctl

I've created a .plist with a StartCalendarInterval key for a program that must run once a day.  It works, and I'm satisfied.  I've also created a python script that reads a config file and will re-run launchctl and reload that plist with a different value of the start time if the time of day specified in the config file is changed.  That works too.  My problem is that somehow an old value of the start time has been preserved somewhere in the system.  If the system reboots and I don't re-run that python script, the start time defaults back to the old value.  I want the start time to default to the most recently specified value.  I've tried every value of the -w and -F flags I can think of to launchctl, but nothing over rides that old stored value.  Can anyone tell me where that old value is being stored and how to over-ride it?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to unload the .plist before loading the new value?

Comment: Yes - the python script explicitly unloads the .plist.  I've also tried using the "remove" command, which uses the program name rather than the plist file.  That didn't work either.